# Search for numbers in files and replace the match with "result -1"

Tags: bash, powershell

I want to subtract 1 from every number before the character '=' in a list of files. For example, rename a string in a file such as "sometext.10.moretext" to "sometext.9.moretext".

I thought this might work:

```
grep -rl "[0-9]*" ./TEST | xargs sed -i "s/[0-9]*/&-1/g"
```

But it merely adds "-1" as a string after my numbers, so that the result is "sometext.10-1.moretext". I'm not really experienced with bash (and using it via windows), is there a way to do this? Powershell would also be an option.

*edit*

**Input**: some.text.10.text=some.other.text.10

**Desired Output**: some.text.9.text=some.other.text.10

**Note**: The actual number can be something from 1 to 9999.

**File names have the following pattern**: text@name#othername.config

Comment: Can you have more digits in the string? Change `7xx89` into `6xx88` or `6xx78` ?

Comment: More digits are not allowed.

Comment: You want to `subtract 1 from every number` yet your desired output still has a 10 in it - is your description wrong or is your example wrong?

Comment: Description is not precise, the example is correct. Sorry & updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |                       # List files
    Select-String -Pattern '[0-9]' -List |     # 'grep' files with numbers
    Foreach-Object {                           # loop over those files

        (Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.Path) |   # read their content
            ForEach-Object {                   # loop over the lines, do regex replace

                [regex]::Replace($_, '[0-9]+', {param($match) ([int]$match.Value) - 1})

        } | Set-Content -Path $_.Path -Encoding ASCII      # output the lines

    }
```

or in short form

```
gci -r|sls [0-9] -lis|% {(gc -lit $_.Path)|%{
    [regex]::Replace($_,'[0-9]+',{"$args"-1})
}|sc $_.Path -enc ascii}
```

Comment: Tested on all files. There seem to be some characters that break the script. (InvalidCastFromStringToInteger). These files are not uniform, there are some lines with different strings / formatting. It's too much to analyse / display here, but thanks nonetheless.

Comment: I've given you the accepted answer, because your solution seems to be the closest.

Comment: @XyFreeman Weird; about the only way I can imagine it breaking with that error is if the run of digits it matches is too big for a 32 bit integer, and you could try `[BigInt]` to fix that. If it's more a case that it's matching digits which are references (GUIDs) and not numbers, well you'd need a much more specific regex/parsing to pick out what you want to change vs. what you don't.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **awk** to achieve this :

I believe your words in strings are delimited by `.` and digits won't appear just before `=` otherwise this will fail as we are using only `.` as the delimiter.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if($i~"=")break; if($i~/^[0-9]+$/){$i=$i-1} }}1'
```

Input :

```
sometext.10.moretext=meow.10.meow
```

Output:

```
sometext.9.moretext=meow.10.meow
```

Comment: Where was the comment about `=`? Also this will fail if the digit is before the `=` without a dot separating them.

Comment: @123: OP has deleted it. Yes It will but the input provided has digits surrounded by words. So I am assuming that is the case. Let me add this in answer too.

Comment: @XyFreeman: Can you add the input and desired output in the Question ?

Comment: @123 The comment on the question with detailed requirements have been deleted. The comment was that digits after the equal sign should remain untouched.

Comment: @WalterA They have written more digits are not allowed in the string though, so not sure why the `=` would even be relevant.

Comment: Everything should now be included in the original question. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @XyFreeman: Makes sense and is more clear now. I've accounted in all your requirements.

Comment: Tested it, even with only one file, it seems to be stuck in a loop. Script doesn't finish.

Comment: @XyFreeman It won't run infinitely. It could be that your filename has special character say `'`. What's the exact name of file you've tested on ?

Comment: Pretty much this: "firstname@secondname#production.config", secondname never changes, first name does from file to file. Everything else doesn't change either.

Comment: @XyFreeman: It's working at my end. I hope you've copied and pasted the complete awk command from this answer i.e starting from `awk '` to `1'`. Are you testing it on command line or in your own script ?

Comment: I double checked, definitely executed "awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if($i~"=")break; if($i~/^[0-9]+$/){$i=$i-1} }}1'"

Comment: @XyFreeman: I'm using GNU Awk 4.1.4 . what's the version of awk you're using. check `awk --version`. And which OS are you on ?

Comment: @batMan: same awk version, but I'm running W10 and use bash via Cygwin. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @XyFreeman: Yes it could be. You can close the current session and start the Cygwin exe again. Another question : When you execute this command do you see `>` on next line ?

Comment: @batMan: Same problem, don't see > but a filled square, so it's still working but I don't know on what exactly. Files don't change at all. I think I'll give up and do this hardcoded for every possible number. Thanks and sorry that I can't tell you why it isn't working on my machine.

Comment: @XyFreeman: I'm sure this is something specific to Cygwin. To clarify something, this will not change the file inplace. You need to store the result in another file like this : `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if($i~"=")break; if($i~/^[0-9]+$/){$i=$i-1} }}1'  firstname@secondname#production.config > output_file`. You can try this and let it work for sometime and see if it stores anything or not.

Comment: @batMan: Ah, I wasn't aware of that. It runs, but the file is empty afterwards. (With your test case from above, too). I don't see how that should be the case, but I'm also tired :). I'm almost done with the hardcoding, so thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
echo "sometext.10.moretext=meow.10.meow" |
   sed -r 's/([^0-9]*)([0-9]*)(.*)/echo "\1$((\2-1))\3"/e'
```

Or changing files under TEST (see EDIT)

```
sed -ri 's/([^0-9]*)([0-9]*)(.*)/echo "\1$((\2-1))\3"/e' $(find ./TEST -type f)
```

EDIT
The `find` command will cause problems when filenames with spaces or newlines are encountered. So you should change the approach:

(Do not use `grep -rlz "[0-9]*" ./TEST`, that failed earlier)

```
   find TEST -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -ri 's/([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1$((\2-1))\3"/e'
```

Comment: Your find will break on any special character filenames.

Comment: That would still break for whitespace, should probably use `-z` on grep and `-0` on xargs

Comment: Files have special characters in them, included that into the original question. But looks really good otherwise.

Comment: Just tested it. That seems to add -1 at the beginning of each line / string.

Comment: Did you change the xargs parameter? I get the message that -o is an unknown option

Comment: Ah, that executes. Now the terminal tells me that the it can't read the file. "sed: can't read ./name@anothername#production.config: No such file or directory". But that's wrong, the name matches 100%.

Comment: I deleted earlier comments, and changed back to using `find`. I hope you find this better too.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo sometext.10.moretext=meow.10.meow| awk '{sub(/10/,"9")}1'

sometext.9.moretext=meow.10.meow
```

Comment: great answer, why not just `echo sometext.9.moretext=meow.10.meow` ?

Comment: Yes, that's another possibility missed that.